# Android Studio Volley JSON REST API Parsing

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Writing Android Application, Need to Parse JSON Data which is nested 
Below is Actual data received from http.

Currently using Volley,

`JSONArray dataJSONArray = response.getJSONArray("data");`

Need example code to parse and display data from below mentioned JSON data

`{"data":[{"counting_area_id":3,"name":"Utilization","parking_area_id":1, "free":3,"total":200,"location_latitude":null,"location_longitude":null,"places":10,
"children":[{"counting_area_id":1,"name":"Basement 1","parking_area_id":1, "free":0,"total":116,"location_latitude":null,"location_longitude":null,"places":0,
"children":[]},{"counting_area_id":73,"name":"Basement 2","parking_area_id":1, "free":3,"total":121,"location_latitude":null,"location_longitude":null,"places":3,
"children":[]}]}]}`

Comment: Follow the How To Ask guide before posting a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask If your question does not fit into the How To Ask guideline, you can try beginner programming forums and groups which will help you better than SO. If you've got precise technical problems with your code then post it on SO. If you do not follow the SO questions guideline your question might be downvoted or closed with no gain or response. Also see: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to passed your `data` to `JSONArray` and parse through it using `for loop` ,like below code :

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");//getting array
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
             JSONObject jsonobject= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);//getting first element 
           String id= jsonobject.getString("counting_area_id");//value of counting_area_id ,get all value in same way i.e location,places etc.
          System.out.println(id);
             JSONArray jsonObject1= object.getJSONArray("children"); //getting children array
     for (int j = 0; j < jsonObject1.length(); j++) {
         JSONObject object1 = jsonObject1.getJSONObject(j);
           String id= object1.getString("counting_area_id");//same as before

        }
        }
```